# .NET Core 3 Endpoint Routing causes redirection to incomplete url

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have set this up in my startup.cs

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints((config) => {
    config.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area}/{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
    config.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{Controller=Home}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
    config.MapRazorPages();
});
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

My login controller is located in /Identity/Account/Login

When the user is authenticated, they are redirected to Home/Index

However, for some reason, when my user is authenticated, they are redirected to /Identity instead

There are no pages on /Identity so it returns a not found page. I will need to manually click on the home link to go to /Home/Index

This was recently migrated from .NET Core 2.2

Have I missed something?

EDIT:

I discovered that after logging in, in the Headers section under Response in the Context, there is a location set which is /Identity.

How do I overwrite that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use razor pages, check your `Login.cshtml.cs`. Ususally the redirect url is set there. It also supports `returnUrl` as a parameter by default in case the user wanted to access a page where authorization is needed.

Just debug it and you will figure it out in no time